# How can I put a .ipa/.apk on a website so people can install it via third party?

Tags: android, ios

I wanted to know how can I upload a .ipa/.apk file to a website so people can download my application via my website? I know people can download third party applications directly to their mobile phones. I wasn't looking for third party app stores as that won't fit what I am trying to achieve. Rather a direct download. I have been doing some research for awhile and I haven't found much luck. I did see https://www.diawi.com as an option however, you have grab users UDID, number of downloads are limited and the it expires after sometime.

Any help would be great,

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not an available distribution method for iOS apps. iOS apps must be signed, either by Apple and installed from the App Store or by the developer and include the device UDID.

Comment: @Paulw11, I have been seeing over air solutions and https://devcenter.bitrise.io/testing/installing-an-ipa-file-from-the-public-install-page/. Is this possible?

Comment: "The public install page enables you to install .ipa files on provisioned and registered test devices" - i.e. devices whose UDIDs are registered in your developer account and included in the provisioning profile.  You can use TestFlight in App Store Connect in a similar way - You can even provide a public beta test URL via TestFlight, but apps delivered in this way do expire after 90 days